# What I am missing here?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

[image: I couldn't understand the logic]

I was solving a problem about complex numbers. After trying for sometime, I looked at the solution. I didn't understand the logic behind their reasoning. Those expressions don't look equal at least to me.

What I am missing? Is it about the fact that the argument of a complex number can be anything between -π and π.

Comment: What are the equalities you do not understand?

Comment: You know $e^{i 2 \pi} = 1$, right?

Comment: Please write an *informative* title that will help others find your question and eventual solutions.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Based on what I see, you are missing a working picture link, and an informative title, and actual information about what you don't get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $e^{i \frac{125\pi}{12}} = e^{i \frac{5\pi}{12}}$

This follows because $\frac{125\pi}{12} = \frac{5\pi}{12} + 10 \cdot \pi = \frac{5\pi}{12} + 5 \cdot 2\pi$, and $e^{2\pi i} = 1$.

> $e^{i \frac{5\pi}{12}} = e^{i \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)}$

$\frac{5}{12}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{12}$

> $e^{i \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{12}\right)} = ie^{-i\frac{\pi}{12}}$

This is because $e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}} = \cos\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{2}= i$.

> $ie^{-i\frac{\pi}{12}}=ie^{i \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}$

$-\frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}$

> $ie^{i \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)} =ie^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}e^{-i \frac{\pi}{3}}$

Property of exponential function.

You could continue to simplify from here by noting that
$$e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}} = \cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
and 
$$e^{-i \frac{\pi}{3}} = \cos -\frac{\pi}{3} + i \sin -\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
So we get
\begin{align*}
e^{i \frac{125\pi}{12}} &= i\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{4}i.
\end{align*}

Comment: This was super helpful. Thank you !